# Emberjs ember-i18n Pluralization not working

Tags: ember.js, internationalization, ember-cli, ember-i18n

i have the following in my en/transaltion.js

```
'AllDogs': {
    'Dogs' :{
        'zero': 'ALL DOGS, ',
        'one': '1 DOG SELECTED',
        'other': '{{count}} DOG SELECTED'  
    }}
```

hbs has the following

```
{{t AllDogs.Dogs count=filteredCount }}
```

Which is not showing anything 
but if i add {{t 'AllDogs.Dogs.one'}} its coming up,  any directions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This need to be handled from the component js, i have added a property for the count. My code is as follows

```
dogsCount : function() {
 var count =  this.get('i18n').t('AllDogs.Dogs ', { count : this.get('ActualCount')});
 return count;
}.property('count'),
```